# In WireMock.Net using WebApi why baseUrl cannot be the uri of the api?

Tags: c#, wiremock

I implemented WireMock.Net into an ASP.NET Core WebApi into program.cs.
The applicationUrl is https://localhost:5001 and have a not used controller in it.

I Would like to mock the requests coming to https:/localhost:5001/home to response the bodyContent object. But it only works when port is different. But in case the mocking won't work because it will place in cloud architecture as microservice.

```
_server = WireMockServer.Start(
           new WireMockServerSettings
           {
             Urls = new[] { "https://localhost:5001"},
             ReadStaticMappings = true
           });

_server.Given(Request.Create()
                   .WithPath("/home"))
                   .RespondWith(
                       Response.Create()
                           .WithStatusCode(200)
                           .WithHeader("Content-Type", "aplication/json")
                           .WithBodyAsJson(bodyContent));
```

Answer (score 0):

WireMock.Net as you use it in your code example, will listen on https://localhost:5001.
But for his to work, you need to only use this code in the Program.cs or use the standalone version.
See https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/WireMock-as-a-standalone-process

Once this is setup, you WebApi project can call WireMock.Net at https://localhost:5001 instead of connecting to the real external service.

I hope this is clear, else you need to explain more what you are trying to achieve.